# Assigning value to dynamic object's property

Tags: php

This is not only tricky to explain, but tricky to do:

I'm trying to access and replace

```
$myObject->customField[0] = "some value";
```

but if I do

```
$str = "customField";
$myObject->$str[0] = "some value";
```

That doesn't work and if I do

```
$str = "customField";
$obj = $myObject->$str;
$obj[0];
```

That won't work either. I can change the values if I don't do this dynamically but I'm having to loop through a lot so doing it dynamic will be very helpful.

## EDIT (answer)

Turns out curly braces does the trick. ie

```
$str = "customField";
$myObject->{$str}[0] = "some value";
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? how are you implementing it anyway? it echoes [fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/C6yuwu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to have dynamic property names? The best answer is: don't do it this way. Consider using an associative array instead:

```
$myObject->customFields = array();

$myObject->customFields[$str] = "some value";
```

Comment: I solved it with curly braces and put the solution inside my question.